# Increment id value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In my SQL I have this query and I want to increase id with this insert that have

I don't want to use `identity(1,1)`

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_waredetails
       (wd_id, wd_mt_code, wd_wa_Id, wd_supply, wd_description, wd_status)
   SELECT    
       (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(wd.wd_id), 0) + 1 
        FROM dbo.tbl_waredetails AS wd), 
       dbo.tbl_material.mat_code, @id,
       dbo.fun_CompRem(mat_code, -1, @user_id) AS supply,
       NULL, 0
   FROM                 
       tbl_material 
   INNER JOIN
       dbo.tbl_MatUnit ON dbo.tbl_material.mat_MatUnt_Code = dbo.tbl_MatUnit.Matunt_code 
   INNER JOIN
       dbo.tbl_MatGroup ON dbo.tbl_material.mat_MatGrp_Code = dbo.tbl_MatGroup.MatGrp_Code
```

but it send always 2 as id

Comment: Using `IDENTITY` is the best and most reliable way to do this - why do you exclude it from the beginning?? Anything **you do** manually is prone to not being concurrency-safe, e.g. producing duplicate values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_waredetails
        (wd_id, wd_mt_code, wd_wa_Id, wd_supply, wd_description, wd_status)
   SELECT    
       (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(wd.wd_id), 0)  
        FROM dbo.tbl_waredetails AS wd)+ (row_number() over (order by wd.wd_id)), 
       dbo.tbl_material.mat_code, @id,    
       dbo.fun_CompRem(mat_code, -1, @user_id) AS supply,
       NULL, 0
   FROM                 
       tbl_material 
   INNER JOIN
       dbo.tbl_MatUnit ON dbo.tbl_material.mat_MatUnt_Code = dbo.tbl_MatUnit.Matunt_code 
   INNER JOIN
       dbo.tbl_MatGroup ON dbo.tbl_material.mat_MatGrp_Code = dbo.tbl_MatGroup.MatGrp_Code
```

Comment: This is the obvious, simplistic way to doing it - too simplistic for a real-life scenario, however, since if multiple clients execute this code at the same time, **duplicate* `wd_id` values will be created.

Comment: it has this error  because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause and user this query but returns null SELECT ISNULL(MAX(wd.wd_id), 0) + (row_number() over (order by wd.wd_id)) 
        FROM dbo.tbl_waredetails AS wd
  GROUP BY wd.wd_id

Comment: Please check once again

Comment: @user3480060 If this helped, please accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as
(select (SELECT isnull(MAX(wd.wd_id),0) FROM dbo.tbl_waredetails ) as iden,dbo.tbl_material.mat_code,@id,    


            dbo.fun_CompRem(mat_code,-1,@user_id
            )as supply,NULL,0
            FROM     tbl_material INNER JOIN
                                  dbo.tbl_MatUnit ON dbo.tbl_material.mat_MatUnt_Code = dbo.tbl_MatUnit.Matunt_code INNER JOIN
                                  dbo.tbl_MatGroup ON dbo.tbl_material.mat_MatGrp_Code = dbo.tbl_MatGroup.MatGrp_Code
where ROW_NUMBER ( ) 
    OVER ( order by 1 )=1

union all

select c.iden+1,dbo.tbl_material.mat_code,@id,    


            dbo.fun_CompRem(mat_code,-1,@user_id
            )as supply,NULL,0
            FROM     tbl_material INNER JOIN
                                  dbo.tbl_MatUnit ON dbo.tbl_material.mat_MatUnt_Code = dbo.tbl_MatUnit.Matunt_code INNER JOIN
                                  dbo.tbl_MatGroup ON dbo.tbl_material.mat_MatGrp_Code = dbo.tbl_MatGroup.MatGrp_Code
join cte as d on 1=1
where ROW_NUMBER ( ) 
    OVER ( order by 1 )!=1

)




INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_waredetails
        ( 
            wd_id,
          wd_mt_code ,
          wd_wa_Id ,
          wd_supply ,
          wd_description ,
          wd_status
        )

    SELECT    iden, dbo.tbl_material.mat_code,@id,supply,NULL,0
            FROM                CTE
```